# Complexity of Perl foreach over hash keys

Tags: perl, complexity-theory

What is complexity of this code?

```
foreach $var (keys %varset) { 
  print "${var}\n";
}
```

Is it O(n^2) or O(n), that is, will keys operation be called on every iteration or just once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's O(n).  When a `foreach` loop begins, the expression is evaluated in list context, and the loop then iterates over that list.  For one thing, there's no guarantee that a subsequent call to `keys` will return the keys in the same order, or even the same keys, so how would it figure out which element was next if it reevaluated the expression?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify which resource, and if you were interested in best, average or worst case, so I'm providing them all.

---

CPU usage of `for (keys %hash)`, both best and worse case, is: Θ(N) to get the keys + Θ(N) to iterate over them = Θ(N)

Memory usage of `for (keys %hash)`, both best and worse case, is: Θ(N) to get the keys + Θ(1) to iterate over them = Θ(N)

Some foreach loops are optimised to use no memory.

Memory usage of `for (NON_CONST_EXPR..NON_CONST_EXPR)`, both best and worse case, is: Θ(1)
Memory usage of `for (@a)`, both best and worse case, is: Θ(1)

---

Θ(f()) is more specific than O(f()). If something is Θ(f()), it's both O(f()) and Ω(f()).